# Robots.txt: Disallow repeated subdirectories but allow main directories

Tags: robots.txt

I have these directories, there are many of them:

```
/dir100/media
/dir200/media
/dir300/media
```

i want to Disallow all */media directories
how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there in your question!

```
# User agent that should be disallowed, '*' is far 'all' 
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/media

# A less restrictive rule that would also work:
# Disallow: /dir*/media
```

In general search engines do want to see every resource that might be referenced from your pages, and if these resources are disallowed for crawling and are critical to understand the pages through rendering, there's a chance Google and other search engines will have a hard time understanding the pages. Keep that in mind when setting up disallow directives.